# How are these definitions of Frechet derivatives related to each other?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

First def. for f exists the fréchet-derivative if there is a continuous operator $T \in L(X,Y)$, such that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0 + hv) - f(x_0)}{h} = Tv$ converges uniformly in $v$, vs.
Second def. $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+ Th + o(h)$.

How do get the uniform convergence from the second one? I guess it is pretty obvious, but I do not see it.

My doubt is, that this definition might not be true for every normed vector space, since not every norm is equivalent to the sup-norm that refers to uniform convergence. Or does uniform convergence for a abstract normed vector space refer to something different than convergence in the sup-norm?

Comment: Well, since you write $Ah$ I assume finite dimensional domain hence the expression $Ah$ can be bounded via looking at the maximum of the finitely many entries in $A$. It then follows the convergence is uniform since the estimate is based soley on $A$ independent of the point considered.

Comment: no,nothing is said about the dimension of the domain. does uniform convergence just mean, that we regard a norm on functions or does it necessarily mean, that we look at the $||.||_{\infty}$ norm?

Comment: The "uniform convergence" of the first definition is not uniform on all of $X$, it is only uniform for $v$ in any bounded subset of $X$; one usually takes the unit ball $B_X$. Then the uniform convergence on $B_X$ of the difference quotients is exactly the $o(h)$ of the second definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "uniform convergence" of the first definition is not uniform convergence on all of $X$. If $f$ is defined only on a proper subset of $X$, it cannot possibly mean that since $f(x_0 + hv)$ isn't defined for all $v$, and even if it is defined on all of $X$, the difference quotient

$$\frac{f(x_0 + hv) - f(x_0)}{h}$$

has no reason whatsoever to be close to $Tv$ when $\lVert v\rVert$ is large, really really large.

What is meant is uniform convergence on bounded subsets of $X$. It is enough to pick one special bounded subset of $X$, the (closed) unit ball $B_X = \{ v\in X : \lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1\}$.

Then the first definition means that the function

$$q(h) := \sup_{v \in B_X} \left\lVert \frac{f(x_0 + hv) - f(x_0)}{h} - Tv\right\rVert\tag{1}$$

has the property that $\lim\limits_{h\downarrow 0} q(h) = 0$.

The second definition means that

$$r(w) := f(x_0+w) - f(x_0) - Aw$$

belongs to $o(w)$, which in turn means

$$\lim_{w\to 0} \frac{r(w)}{\lVert w\rVert} = 0,$$

and that means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\lVert w\rVert < \delta \Rightarrow \lVert r(w)\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon\cdot \lVert w\rVert,$$

or, with $w_0 = \frac{1}{\lVert w\rVert}\cdot w$ for $w \neq 0$,

$$\sup_{\lVert w_0\rVert = 1,\, h < \delta} \left\lVert \frac{f(x_0 + hw_0) - f(x_0)}{h} - Aw_0\right\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon.\tag{2}$$

Now, if we write $v = t\cdot v_0$ with $\lVert v_0\rVert = 1$ and $t\in [0,1]$ in $(1)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\left\lVert \frac{f(x_0 + htv_0)-f(x_0)}{h} - T(tv_0)\right\rVert &= t\cdot \left\lVert \frac{f(x_0+htv_0) - f(x_0)}{th} - Tv_0\right\rVert\\
&\leqslant \left\lVert \frac{f(x_0+htv_0) - f(x_0)}{th} - Tv_0\right\rVert,
\end{align}$$

so we have

$$\sup_{h < \delta} \sup_{\lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1}\left\lVert \frac{f(x_0+hv) - f(x_0)}{h} - Tv\right\rVert = \sup_{h < \delta} \sup_{\lVert v\rVert = 1}\left\lVert \frac{f(x_0+hv) - f(x_0)}{h} - Tv\right\rVert,\tag{3}$$

and $\lim\limits_{h\downarrow 0} q(h) = 0$ is equivalent to the second definition, since with regard to $(3)$, it reduces to $(2)$.

Comment: Do you agree that $Av$ denotes matrix multiplication? Just curious, nice answer.

Comment: Not necessarily. For linear operators, it is quite common to leave off the parentheses (we're lazy bastards), since they are like matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you again. One last question. I see this right: Uniform convergence does not mean, that you (necessarily) look at the maximum-norm that we for example "almost always" have on $C[0,1]$, but it is rather a general expression for every normed vector space to look at the supremum of the particular norm for a variable, right?

Comment: It does mean that you look at the supremum of some (distance) function over some set. You're not always dealing with vector spaces, so it's not always a norm, but the principle is the same. The thing is to figure out the supremum of which function over which set. That's not always stated as clearly as would be desirable. Here the parameter is $h$, the set $B_X$, and the function is $$Q_h(v) = \left\lVert \frac{f(x_0+hv)-f(x_0)}{h} - Tv\right\rVert.$$